# Programmatically bind to 2D observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>` that i am trying to bind each string to.

Here's what I tried.

```
txtBlock = new TextBox();
Binding txtBind = new Binding();
txtBind.Source = exportData;
txtBind.Path = new PropertyPath("exportData", i, j);
                    //txtBlock.Text = exportData[i][j];
BindingOperations.SetBinding(txtBlock, TextBlock.TextProperty, txtBind);
```

It populates TextBoxes with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I rarely write bindings in code.  It's my understanding the propertypath should be the same string as you would use in xaml.

You could use string interpolation to arrange that.

Hence

```
 txtBind.Path = new PropertyPath($"exportData[{i}][{j}]");
```

Assuming exportData is your 2d collection.

Don't set source.

Ensure the datacontext of the textblock is a viewmodel with a public property of exportData.

And make sure you bind matching control type.text.

You have a textbox and are binding textblock.textproperty.

Different controls.

This works for me.

I have a viewmodel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> exportData { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>();
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        exportData.Add(new ObservableCollection<string>(new List<string> { "AA", "BB", "CC" }));
        exportData.Add(new ObservableCollection<string>(new List<string> { "AAa", "BBb", "CCc" }));
        exportData.Add(new ObservableCollection<string>(new List<string> { "AAaa", "BBbb", "CCcc" }));
```

In MainWindow

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var txtBlock = new TextBlock();
        MyGrid.Children.Add(txtBlock);
        Binding txtBind = new Binding();
        int i = 0;
        int j = 1;
        var cd = DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
        txtBind.Path = new PropertyPath($"exportData[{i}][{j}]");
        txtBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, txtBind);
    }
```

Or

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var txtBlock = new TextBox();
        MyGrid.Children.Add(txtBlock);
        Binding txtBind = new Binding();
        int i = 0;
        int j = 1;
        var cd = DataContext as MainWindowViewModel;
        txtBind.Path = new PropertyPath($"exportData[{i}][{j}]");
        txtBlock.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, txtBind);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `Source` of the binding to an `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>`, the binding path should be "[i][j]".

Also, a you cannot bind the `TextBlock.TextProperty` of a `TextBox`. Either `txtBlock` should be a `TextBlock`, or you should bind to `TextBox.TextProperty`.

This works:

```
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>> exportData =
                new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<string>>();
exportData.Add(new ObservableCollection<string>() { "abc" });
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

TextBox txtBlock;
txtBlock = new TextBox();
Binding txtBind = new Binding();
txtBind.Source = exportData;
txtBind.Path = new PropertyPath($"[{i}][{j}]");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(txtBlock, TextBox.TextProperty, txtBind);
```